# Jersey Spring MVC Counterparts

Tags: spring-mvc, jersey

I attended a class on Spring where he spoke at length about Spring MVC. My shop uses Spring for DI but Jersey instead of MVC. Is there a quick guide to the cross reference b/w Spring MVC and Jersey? like for instance SpringMVC seems to use @RequestMapping extensively, Jersey has @Path instead...

Comment: May I know what exactly you are looking here?

Comment: Sure. Like I said I underwent SpringMVC training but my shop uses Jersey. I know they kinda sorta do the same thing but using different annotations. I am trying to analogise between the two kinds of annotations- like the example I gave b/w RequestMapping and Path. Or that on the SpringMVC side the "entry point" class extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer whereas in Jersey it seems to be (not sure here) WebApplicationInitializer.